# $71\nmid a$ and $x^7\equiv a\pmod {71}$ has an integer solution. How many positive integer solution there is for this equation that lower than 71?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need a little help with the following question:

> If $a$ is an integer such as $71\nmid a$ and $x^7\equiv a\pmod {71}$ has an integer solution. How many positive integer solution there is for this equation that lower than 71?

All I understand is that $71$ is prime.

And that because $71\nmid a$ then $\gcd (a,71) = 1$ so we know there is $s,t\in \mathbb Z$ such as $sa+71t=1$ then $71t=1-sa$ then $71 \mid 1-sa$ then $sa \equiv 1\pmod {71}$.

If $c$ is a solution then $c^7\equiv a\pmod {71}$ then $71\mid c^7-a.$

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are both solutions, then, working $\pmod {71}$,  $xy^{-1}$ has order $7$.  How many elements have order $7$?

Comment: If I know that $x,y$ are both solutions then $x^7\equiv y^7 \equiv a  \pmod {71}$ but why $xy^{-1} \equiv 7 \pmod {71}$?

Comment: I think @lulu meant $(xy^{-1})^7\equiv 1\pmod {71}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks @fantasie. Now I can understand that (${(xy^{-1})}^7 \equiv \frac{a}{a} = 1 \pmod {71}$). But how is it helping me?

Comment: Why not just make a spreadsheet and see?  There are only $70$ to check.  Copy down will make it quick.

Comment: @RossMillikan, You don't n=know what is $a$. ;)

Comment: @Thestudent:  you can just see how many different numbers are in the column of $nx^7 \pmod{71}$.  You can sort that column to make counting easier.

Comment: $7$ solutions for each of $a$: $1, 5, 14, 17, 25, 46, 54, 57, 66, 70$, python 2 lines code [here](https://tio.run/##LcyxCoNADADQ3a/ImMAt0kEROvVL5Hpq4ExCjJR@/dmC6xuefWNTeYzmrS2uO2StteRglQN4N/WAl54SxTtzlkDM0/MWNP0gpyENPcGiDgws4LOsBfs/EiU4fkV5YyZq7QI). @Thestudent

Comment: @Thestudent FYI, a similar, but more general, version of your question is in [Prove an interesting result involving repetition when raising integers to a power, mod p.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3770586/602049).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group mod a prime $p$ is cyclic. A generator of this group is called a primitive root mod $p$.  If $b$ is a primitive root, it means for each $x \in \{1,\ldots, p-1\}$ we can write $x \equiv b^j \mod p$ for some unique $j \in \{1,\ldots, p-1\}$. $b$ has order $p-1 \mod p$.  It turns out, for example, that $11$ is a primitive root mod $71$, but you don't need to know that for this question, you only need to know the theorem that a primitive root exists for each prime.

If $d$ is any divisor of $p-1$ and $x^d \equiv 1 \mod p$ where $x \equiv b^j \mod p$, that says $b^{jd} \equiv 1 \mod p$, so $jd$ must be divisible by $p-1$.  So, the number of such $x$ is the same as the number of $j \in \{1, \ldots, p-1\}$ such that $p-1 \mid jd$.  So in your case, how many members $j$ of $\{1,\ldots, 70\}$ are there such that $7j$ is divisible by $70$?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the question premised that it has a solution. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both solutions, then $(xy^{-1})^7\equiv1\pmod {71}$. Conversely, fix a solution $x$, if $u^7 \equiv 1 \pmod{71}$, then $xu$ is another solution. So there is a bijection
$$\{\textrm{solutions of the original equation}\} \leftrightarrow \{u|u^7\equiv 1 \pmod {71}\}$$
But we know that $\mathbb Z_{71}^{\times} \cong \mathbb Z_{70}$, so there are exactly 7 solutions of $u^7\equiv 1 \pmod {71}$. (Alternatively, you may pass this step with the theory of primitive roots)

Comment: I don't know what is this $\mathbb Z_{71}^{\times} \cong \mathbb Z_{70}$...

Comment: @Thestudent It meant that the multiplication group of the ring $\mathbb Z_{71}$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $70$. This is a classical result of group theory, but the same nature can be expressed equivalently with primitive roots. See Robert’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalize here: Let (P,k) be a prime and an exponent, such that P is congruent to 1 (mod k).  The non-zero integers mod P form a cyclic group under multiplication, of order P-1.  Therefore there is some positive $a$ such that $a^{P-1} = 1$ (mod P) *and P-1 is the smallest q s.t. $a^q = 1$*.  Since P-1 = k * m for some m, we see that $(a^m)^k = 1$ (mod P) and so b = $a^m$ is a solution for this (P,k).  We can also see that for any n, $a^{n*(P-1)} = (a^{n*m})^k = (b^n)^k = 1$ also, so a complete set of solutions for (P,k) is $b$, $b^2$, ..., $b^{k-1}$, $b^k = 1$.

In particular, your (71,7) case has precisely seven solutions for $x^7 = 1$ (mod 71).